# Showing related entities when delete

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate, cascade

I have a model with some relations mapped with NHibernate and it is working fine, for sample:

```
public class A
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   // other properties

   public ICollection<B> BList { get; set; }
   public ICollection<C> CList { get; set; }
   public ICollection<D> DList { get; set; }
}
```

The persistence and reading for this kind of entity works very fine, but when the user will delete a `A` entity, 
I would like to show him that there are one or more entities related (not what entity (id, name etc..) but the what  type of entity), for sample:

```
You cannot delete this register because there are relations with:

-B
-D
```

(if a `A` entity, has `B`'s or `D`'s relations and not `C`'s).

I know I can get this information checking entity by entity, but I would like to have a generic solution, Is there any way?!

Comment: What's your mapping solution? HBML, Fluent...?

Comment: I'm using fluent nhibernate..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NHibernate has its own metadata API, which allows you to read all mapping information, including which collections are mapped to properties, and what are the property types.
From type of each property, you can find out the name of related type.

```
A instance = ...
var metaData = this.session.SessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(instance.GetType());
foreach(IType propertyType in metaData.PropertyTypes)
{
  if(propertyType.IsCollectionType)
  {
    var name = propertyType.Name;
    var collectionType = (NHibernate.Type.CollectionType)propertyType;
    var collection = collectionType.GetElementsCollection(instance);
    bool hasAny = collection.Count > 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but how could I check if there is data on theses collections?!

Comment: Updated my answer - you can extract actual collection by providing instance.

Comment: Thank you for your awnser Alexander, but, do you know if there is any way to extract this information from the Exception of Cascade?!

Comment: where can I find the `collectionType.GetElementsCollection(instance);` namespace?

Comment: Refer to nhibernate docs at http://elliottjorgensen.com/nhibernate-api-ref/NHibernate.Type/CollectionType.html, see CollectionType. It has GetElementsCollection method.